# Amazon Linuxでphpが使えません: The requested URL was not found on this server

Tags: php, linux, amazon-linux

プログラミング初心者です。
Amazon Linux上のデータベースにあるデータを表示するアプリを作っています。 httpdを入れてブラウザから見れるようにしようとしています。

使用したコマンド:

```
sudo yum install httpd -y

ls
datalink.php webpage.zip

sudo service httpd start
```

ブラウザから
http://ec2-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.ap-northeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com/test_server/datalink.php

にアクセスすると

```
Not Found
The requested URL was not found on this server.
```

と出てしまい、

デベロッパーツールで見ると

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
```

と出ておりファイルが見つからないということになってしまいます。
やはりWebサーバが正しくインストール出来ていないのでしょうか…

どなたかご教授をお願い致します。

Comment: 何をどうインストールしてどのような設定で動かしているのかの情報が欲しいです。関係しそうなものを全部追記いただけませんでしょうか。

Comment: わかりました。現段階ではhttpdのみをインストールしてそのままにしています。

Comment: httpd はWebサーバなので更にWebサーバがphpを利用できるようにphpインストールしたり、httpdの設定をする必要があります。その内容はいささか質問範囲が広い印象があります。ぜひ書籍やWeb記事を参考にして試してみてください。

Answer (score 1):

apacheの設定ファイル、httpd.confのドキュメントルートの設定で指定されているディレクトリ以下に、表示したいファイルは保存されていますか？おそらくエラーメッセージの通り、その場所に閲覧したいファイルがないものと思います。